# Can I ignore comments on diff using regular expressions?

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I have to do a file comparison but I want you to exclude the comments
for now it gives me a result like this.

At the moment I am using:
     `diff -b -B [patch] [patch]`
which gives me:

```
< #<Location /bancochile>
< #        WeblogicHost bgri.wls.ri
< #        WeblogicPort 20015
< #        SetHandler weblogic-handler
< #</Location>
< 
45c39,43
```

Comment: And what result were you hoping for?

Comment: Pipe the output of `diff` to `grep -v` to filter out lines you don't want.

Comment: Are you looking for the `-I` option of GNU `diff`?

Comment: BTW, do you just want to know if the uncommented contents differ? That's much simpler/easier than calculating a diff with the shortest possible edit that transforms one to the other, which is `diff`'s job. `cmp` does that easier task much more quickly.

Comment: I just want you not to compare the comments

Answer (score 2):

I suggest with bash:

```
diff -b -B <(grep -v '^#' patch1) <(grep -v '^#' patch2)
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393224/can-i-use-a-regular-expression-using-with-diff-i-need-to-ignore-the-comments#comment85789717_49393224), GNU `diff` has support explicitly for this purpose:

```
diff -I '^[[:space:]]*[#]' -b -B old.cfg new.cfg
```

That said, if you only want to know if there are or are not changes, it's much more efficient to use `cmp`:

```
if cmp -s <(grep -E -v '^[[:space:]]*[#]' <old.cfg) \
          <(grep -E -v '^[[:space:]]*[#]' <new.cfg); then
  echo "Excluding comments, these files are identical"
fi
```